# how to get all child node in treeview of YUI

Tags: javascript, yui

I want all the childs of given node in YUI treeview. Condition is that if the child has sub-childs then I want sub-sub-child. that is all the childs of given node including subchilds.

I think recursion may be the solution for this problem.Can anyone help me out this.

My current code is

```
if(curNode.hasChildren()) {
  for(var child = 0; child < curNode.children.length;child++) {
    alert(curNode.children[child].label);
   }
}
```

By this code, I only get the childrens of given node and not the sub-sub-child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var root = $("#root")[0];
var nodeList = [];

function appendChildren(node, array) {
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            if (node.children[i].hasChildNodes()) {
                appendChildren(node.children[i], array);
                array.push(node.children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

appendChildren(root, nodeList);
```

Tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/yCU54/).

A recursive solution. This can be done more elegantly using functional style programming. This one relies on [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for a cross browser `.reduce` implementation. You can rely on array.reduce if you target newer browsers.

```
function nodeToChildren(node) {
    if (node.hasChildren()) {
        _.reduce(node.children, function (memo, val) {
            return memo.concat(nodeToChildren(val));
        }, [].concat(node));
    } else {
        return node;
    }
}

var array = nodeToChildren(root);
```

Give me a few moments to test/debug this.

I forgot the [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com/) option

`var array = $(root).find("*").toArray()`

Comment: var root = $("#root")[0];
var nodeList = [];

function appendChildren(node, array) {
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            if (node.children[i].hasChildNodes()) {
                array.push(node.children[i]);
            }                                      appendChildren(node.children[i], array);
        }
    }
}

appendChildren(root, nodeList);

Comment: Worked like a charm and saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the root node :
          var root = tree.getRoot();
          tree_traversal(root);

Then you can get its children

```
function tree_traversal(node){
     if(node.hasChildren)    {
         var nodes = node.children;
         for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)    {
             var test_node = nodes[i];
             var label = test_node.label;

         }
     }
```

}

Make the above function recursive and there you go!!Bingo

Answer (score -3):

getAllChildren: function (fromNode) {
                if (fromNode.hasChildren()) {
                    for (var k in fromNode.children) {
                        if (fromNode.children[k].hasChildren()) {
                             CategoryMaster.getAllChildren(fromNode.children[k]);
                        }
                        nodeList.push(fromNode.children[k]);
                    }
                }
            },